# how to restore the previous state of my application after the user uses the browser back button?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react and redux to implement my application. it happens to me that if I click on the browser button, I move to the previous view (which is fine) but I lose the previous state. I want to know how I could restore my previous state. thanks in advance.

redux-undo library helps me to recover my previous state after clicking on the browser back button?

Comment: That's how redux works. Clicking back button reloads the page, browser downloads the app again and previous data is lost. To keep data you can use library like redux-persist for saving it in local storage.

Comment: I am using redux-persist but until the moment only for authentication.